# From Header Parameter Tag in SipSessionKey is `null`

Tags: java, session, sip, sip-servlet

I'm working on an application, where the `SIPSession` generated by *Mobicents* has one of it's attribute coming as `null`. After digging through the source code, I found out that, the value returned from the [`SipSession#getId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13153_01/wlcp/wlss40/javadoc/jsr289/javax/servlet/sip/SipSession.html#getId%28%29) method is nothing but the `SessionKey`.

The `SessionKey` internally uses 4 different parameters to generate the String representation of the key. Out of that, one of the attribute is: `fromTag`. You can look at the source code of [`SipSessionKey` here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.mobicents.servlet.sip/sip-servlets-impl/1.1/org/mobicents/servlet/sip/core/session/SipSessionKey.java#SipSessionKey.0fromTag). Now, I'm unable to understand, what exactly is that `fromTag`. When I saw the request which is being sent, there is definitely a vlaue in the `From` header of the `SipRequest`. The `From` header is in the form:

```
From: <tel:+xxxxxxxxx>
```

That's it. What is `fromTag` in there? Why I'm getting it as `null`?

Comment: May be helpful : http://www.opensips.org/html/docs/modules/1.6.x/rr.html#append-fromtag-id ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [section 8.1.1.3 of RFC 3261](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-8.1.1.3), the `From` header MUST have a `tag` parameter. This is one of the pieces of data used to identify the dialog. (The others are `Call-ID` and the `tag` on the `To` header, generated by the UAS.) One the examples shown in the RFC is:

```
From: sip:+12125551212@phone2net.com;tag=887s
```

When looking at the SIP message received by the Mobicents container, is there a `tag` parameter on the `From` header?

Comment: Thank you so much for that section number. I was unable to find that. That solved the issue :)

Comment: Hi. Can you give an idea of how those tags should be generated? I'm using Jain SIP Stack.

Comment: did you try to use UtilsExt.generateTag() http://hudson.jboss.org/hudson/job/jain-sip/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/javadoc/gov/nist/javax/sip/UtilsExt.html#generateTag()